# Questions about List items' Attachments. Can we link them with custom columns + Can we allow them to appear on search

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, search, search-results, attachments

I am working on a online sharepoint site collection, and i have attached files to custom list items, as follow:-

[image]

But i have the following questions:-

1. can i link the attachment with cusotm columns? so for example when users upload an attachment file, to select its type from a drop-down site column?
2. when i search for the list items' attachments, then inside the search result i will get the item's dispform.aspx and not the actual attachment file. so is there a way to force the search to show the attached file instead of showing the item's dispform.aspx? 
   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default there is no Managed property assigned to Attachment field in List. Also there is no other way via Search to figure out if a list item contains an attachment or not. SharePoint does crawl the attachment and if we search on title or content of the document it will give the list item as the search result but not vice-versa.

In order to show the documents also along with List Item, you can try to modify the Hover panel of the List Item to show the Attachments.

More information, you can refer to the link(also should work on SharePoint Online):
[SharePoint 2013 attachments in ListItem to show in Search Result / Hover panel](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2013-attachments-1a15e1af)